# How to get a span innertext when selector name includes tabs and space characters with excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following html:

```html
<div class="                        product-price
">                
                <span   itemprop="price" content="3.99" class="price-value-11442"  >
                    3,99€
                </span>
```

I copied to notepad++ and it displays 5 tabs and 4 spaces. How to get the innertext of span? The following is not working, it shows nothing:

```
    Set price = ie.Document.querySelector(".product-price .price")
    wks.Cells(i, "C").Value = price.innerText
```

Comment: Where is the "price" class in your posted HTML ?

Comment: You mean it should be Set price = ie.Document.querySelector(".price")

Comment: More like `ie.Document.querySelector(".product-price")` - I don't see "price" anywhere in your posted HTML

Comment: Thank you its working only with .product-price. So I should not worry if there are empty spaces. I thought I should have used first div class and  then span itemprop name

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned there is no child .price class evident. You can use an attribute css selector as well of

```
ie.document.querySelector("[itemprop=price]").innerText
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?